# Track one unique solution among all multiple solutions of a nonlinear equation system

Tags: nonlinear-system

In my engineering problem, there are about 30 variables and 30 nonlinear equations, and there can be more than 100 solutions. Only one unique solution is what I need. The following system is a simple one:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3x_4=0$$
$$x_5+x_3+x2x_6=0$$
$$x_6+x_4+x_1x_5=0$$
$$-9054x_5=0$$
$$1406x_2-1507x_5+2449x_6+4768x_3+2449x_5x_2-5370x_5x_3+9802x_2x_6+1406x_6x_3-5370=0$$
$$-8207x_3-4794=0$$
When there is a perturbation on one of the coefficients(I mean the coefficients which are not 1), the system of equation becomes a different one. For this new problem, is it possible to track the previous unique solution without solving all of the solutions?

I have tried some local optimization method like gradient descent, but it's easy to fall into local minimum and it cannot be proved that the obtained solution is exactly corresponding to the previous one.

Comment: Edit your question to contain the relevant equations.

Comment: If you're just looking for an answer, try [Bertini](https://bertini.nd.edu).

Comment: Thank you, Michael. It seems that Bertini is also a tool like Groeber Basis which just gives all of the solutions. What I want is to track a "unique solution" corresponding to the previous one.